# Tiled service or not?

Tags: arcgis-server, wms, tiles, map-service, tile-map-service

How to know if a

- WMS
- ArcGIS mapservice

are tiled or not?
Which test can answers to the question?

Comment: JavaScript Client libraries that allow you to specify tiled/or not for a WMS service, aren't relying on the WMS service being tiled or not (because WMS don't support tiling), rather it affects the type of request made to the server, either a single image to cover the map canvas, or several small ones

Comment: However, for example OpenLayers in the tiled WMS mode adds &tiled=true and that allows caching on the client side, and WMS-C capable server to utilize its own cache https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-tiled.html.

Answer (score 4):

The WMS standard does not support tiling, but the OSGeo organization defined a long time ago a well defined profile to use WMS as tiled https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/WMS_Tile_Caching.

At least GeoWebCache https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/using.html, MapProxy https://mapproxy.org/docs/nightly/services.html#wms-c, and MapCache https://mapserver.org/mapcache/services.html support WMS-C. All these servers use the same vendor parameter `&tiled=true`. User can check if WMS server supports WMS-C by checking the capabilities with a request like

```
https://server.com?SERVICE=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetCapabilities&tiled=true
```

At least today this WMS-C server is open and online

http://ingunet.net/mapcache/?LAYERS=test&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&tiled=true

WMS-C servers add the information about the supported TileSets into GetCapabilities

```
<VendorSpecificCapabilities>
<TileSet>
<SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
<BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:4326" minx="-180.000000" miny="-90.000000" maxx="180.000000" maxy="90.000000"/>
<Resolutions>0.70312500000000000000 0.35156250000000000000 0.17578125000000000000 0.08789062500000000000 0.04394531250000000000 0.02197265625000000000 0.01098632812500000000 0.00549316406250000000 0.00274658203125000000 0.00137329101562500000 0.00068664550781250000 0.00034332275390625000 0.00017166137695312500 0.00008583068847656250 0.00004291534423828120 0.00002145767211914060 0.00001072883605957030 0.00000536441802978516 </Resolutions>
<Width>256</Width>
<Height>256</Height>
<Format>image/png</Format>
<Layers>test</Layers>
<Styles/>
</TileSet>
```

ESRI has never supported WMS-C https://community.esri.com/t5/open-and-interoperable-questions/wms-c/td-p/8878. Generally speaking WMS-C was an early trial to add support for tiling into OGC services and it became mostly needless when OGC published the WMTS standard.

Comment: GetCapabilities without the tiled parameter, reveals the tile capability if one exists

Comment: Some servers reveal, some don't. GeoWebCache does not mention tile capability when the capabilities are read with http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities